# Confused on how to print my histogram?

Tags: c

So in my code is able to calculate length of each word and increments the index based on the word length. I want to be able to print a vertical histogram. I tried a few different ways and I can't seem to make it work. The code shown below prints out how many times you see a word length of 7 for example. I could copy someone's code who already has an answer to this question, but I really want to learn how the initial skeleton is built and on top of that my data is populated to build the histogram. I would really like an explanation of how that works! This program is from C Programming Ritchie and Kernighan. Chapter 1.6 Exercise 13. Thank you for help in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int c, wc, i;
    int lenword[10];
    wc = 0;

    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        lenword[i] = 0;
    }

    while((c=getchar()) != EOF && wc < 10) //Thanks to ClapTrap point out adding wc<10
    {
        if (c == ' ' || c == '\t' || c == '\n')
        {
            if (wc > 0)
            {
                lenword[wc - 1]++;
                wc = 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            wc++;
        }
    }

    for(i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        printf("Length of index = %d is %d\n", i + 1, lenword[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should show your best effort so we can help you fix it. Assuming the code above prints out the correct data (it looks plausible, though I've not compiled it, much less run it), then you need to decide how you are going to scale your output (what happens if you profile a copy of the Bible, or all of Shakespeare?), and think about whether 10 is long enough (there are definitely words like internationalization and antidisestablishmentarianism or floccinaucinihilipilification that would blow the limits). You should think how you would draw the graph manually, and then repeat that in your code.

Comment: @user2522055 You need explanation for vertical histrogram or horizontal histrogram.

Comment: I didn't get output of this program?
http://shrib.com/kqTO8uuo 
see I gave 5 input strings and got the results as `Length of i 1 is 1`. what is this?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I tried manually printing * to make a vertical line then horizontal line instead of using a for loop or something, but I can't figure out how to find the data that holds the number of occurrences in the word because the vertical line will go up that many times. I did not factor in the questions you had into the problem. The input has to be regular characters with no numbers between 1 to 10 characters in length later on I was going to build on catch outliers.

Comment: @ Gaurav Jain The answer is correct because the single character word is initialized in array[0] position but print like Length of character 1 is 1.

Comment: @Chandru I am trying to print a histogram on the y axis it will hold the number of occurrences and on the x access the length of the word from 1 - 10. I need to draw the y-axis first based on what the largest number of occurrences is in the incremented values of the index.

Comment: @GauravJain I am editing the code so that it prints index = 1 and so on so you know that the index is equivalent to the length of a word

Comment: @user2522055 you should also check that the length of the word doesn't exceed 10 e.g. `while (c=getchar()) != EOF && wc < 10)`

Comment: You should put the word-length check just before the assignment, so that long words are read in normally, only not stored: `if (wc <= MAX) lenword[wc - 1]++;` Your current code will stop reading after encountering a long word.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17390074/] provides a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use gnuplot (GPL licensed, thus free to use) if it is available for you. You can have it on linux systems and it can be downloaded for windows as well, although I only used it under linux.

For that you could print two columns like

```
printf("Index\tLength\n");
for(i=0; i<10; i++)
    printf("%d\t%d\n", i + 1, lenword[i]);
```

Then run your compiled program like

```
./your-program > word-lengths.data
```

Then you can use a gnuplot script embedded into a bash script like this skeleton:

```
#!/bin/bash

if test $# -lt 1; then
        echo "Usage:"
        echo "  $(basename $0) list_of_gnuplot_data_files"
        echo
        exit
fi

while test "x$1" != "x"; do
        NAME=$(basename ${1%.data})
        gnuplot << EOF
        set title "Diagram title"

        set key left top
        set style data lines
        set grid

        set autoscale x
        set xtics nomirror
        set xlabel "Word lengths"

        set autoscale y
        set ytics nomirror
        set ylabel "Word count"

        set output "${NAME}.png"
        set terminal png nocrop enhanced font verdana 12 size 1900,900
        plot    "${NAME}.data" using 1:2 title columnhead axes x1y1
EOF
        shift
done
```

So to use it you can write:

```
./gnuplot-script word-lengths.data
```

It will create a word-lengths.png. You can use pure gnuplot script as well without bash part, but for me this was the most convenient way so far.